# I want split one component in 2 components React JS

Tags: reactjs, api, google-maps, components, searchbar

I'v a problem because I would split one component in two components.
I build my component with a search bar with autocomplete and the map with a pin chosen with the search bar. And me, I would one component with searcbar and an other with map who comunicate the date between them.

But I don't no how make this ..
Somebody could help me ?
Sorry for my Enlish, I'm French

Here is the code of my component:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
    import {Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';
    import PlacesAutocomplete, {
      geocodeByAddress,
      getLatLng,
    } from 'react-places-autocomplete';
    import Child2 from '../Child2';
    
    const Location = createContext();
    
    function Searchbar() {
    
        const [address, setAdress] = useState("")
        const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({
          lat: null,
          lng: null
        })
    
        const handleSelect = (value, props) => {
          const results = await geocodeByAddress(value);
          const ll = await getLatLng(results[0])
          console.log(ll)
          setAdress(value)
          setCoordinates(ll)
          props.OnSelectPlace(ll)
        }
    
        return (
          <div className="Searchbar">
    
            <p>{coordinates.lat}</p>
            <p>{coordinates.lng}</p>
            <p>{address}</p>
    
          <PlacesAutocomplete
            value={address}
            onChange={setAdress}
            onSelect={handleSelect}
          >
            {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
              <div>
                <input
                  {...getInputProps({
                    placeholder: 'Search Places ...',
                    className: 'location-search-input',
                  })}
                />
                <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
                  {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                  {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                    const className = suggestion.active
                      ? 'suggestion-item--active'
                      : 'suggestion-item';
                    // inline style for demonstration purpose
                    const style = suggestion.active
                      ? { backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4', cursor: 'pointer' }
                      : { backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8', cursor: 'pointer' };
                    return (
                      <div
                        {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                          className,
                          style,
                        })}
                      >
                        <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </PlacesAutocomplete>
    
          </div>
        );
    }
    
    export {Location};
    export default GoogleApiWrapper({
      apiKey: ("secret_code_api_google_map")
    })(Searchbar)
```

Comment: The two components need a parent component to speak to eachother: a parent component renders both searchbar and map separately, when the searchbar has the result, it tells it to the parent, whom can then pass it to the map component

Answer (score 0):

Build two separate components one for the map and other for the searchbar. Then pass date as a prop to the second component.